# jvm.dll failed to load error in aix 7.1

Tags: java, aix

How do I resolve the below error in AIX 7.1

bash-4.2# /usr/java5/jre/bin/java -version

jvm.dll failed to load: global entrypoints not found

Failed to find VM - aborting

Also, the environmental variables are

bash-4.2# echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/java5/jre/bin/j9vm:/usr/java5/jre/bin

bash-4.2# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

/usr/java5/jre/bin:/usr/java5/jre/bin/j9vm

bash-4.2# echo $JAVA_HOME

/usr/java5/jre

bash-4.2# echo $DLL

/usr/java5/jre/bin/j9vm/libjvm.so

Comment: Can you post output of "ldd /usr/java5/jre/bin/j9vm/libjvm.so" ?

Comment: bash-4.2# ldd /usr/java5/jre/bin/j9vm/libjvm.so
/usr/java5/jre/bin/j9vm/libjvm.so needs:
         ./libjsig.so
         ./libj9thr23.so
         /usr/lib/libc_r.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libC.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5.o)
         /unix
         /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libC.a(shrcore.o)
         /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_comm.o)
         /usr/lib/libC.a(ansicore_32.o)

Comment: AIX doesn't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DLL` What version of Java you did you install? (`lslpp -l | grep -i java`)

Comment: Google found: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=b80749a0-9c05-49e0-bdd2-a1f303182204